# trying to create a guard to check if an input comes back as NaN

Tags: swift, swift3, decimal, nan

I have an input field that allows user to input numbers( the string is converted to a decimal), but there is an occasion where they could be a $ an no number, in that case I would like to use a guard and pop up an UIAlert letting the user know of the mistake. I read that there is a BOOL property of isNaN for Decimal in Swift 3, but I'm not entirely sure how to use it. This is what I'm trying

```
guard myDecimalNumber != isNaN else {
        print("this is not a number show alert")
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isNan` is a boolean property of `Decimal` (and all floating point
types), so you can check it with

```
guard !myDecimalNumber.isNaN else {
    // ... `myDecimalNumber` is NaN ...
}
```

But note that creating a `Decimal` from a string returns an 
optional which is `nil` if the conversion fails, so what
you probably want is optional binding:

```
guard let myDecimalNumber = Decimal(string: textField.text) else {
    // ... `textField.text` does not represent a number ...
}
```

(and the same approach works for other number types like
`Double`, `Int`, ...)

For proper handling of localized decimal separators, use a
number formatter:

```
guard let myDecimalNumber = formatter.number(from: textField.text)?.decimalValue else {
    // ... `textField.text` does not represent a number ...
}
```